# Is it possible to make a Material ui element(Select) disable on hover?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanna do something like this when the user hover on an element:

document.getElementById("dropdownCategory").disabled = true;

```
        <Tooltip arrow placement="right" title={props.description} >
            <FormControl id="dropdownCategory" >
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" >{props.title} - {props.price}€</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    value={category[props.id]}
                    onChange={handleCategory}
                    name={props.id}
                >
                    {numbers.map(l => (
                        <MenuItem value={l} key={l}>{l}</MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </Tooltip>
```

This is my component and I want to make it disable when the user go by mouse over it

Comment: Can you share some code? We cannot understand the scenario with just one line of code :)

Comment: It would be helpful to have some description of **why** you want to disable on hover. It seems like a horrible thing to do to a user. I would expect there is some other, more important condition in play as well -- otherwise why have a `Select` that the user isn't allowed to interact with?

Comment: Actually I wanna do it in other way, select is disable by default and when the user hover on it it will be active. There will be several selects items but only one of them can be active which is the hovered one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the enabled state of the `Select` based on whether or not the mouse is over it, you can toggle the `disabled` property based on when the mouse enters and leaves the component.

First, you would need to setup a property to track whether the mouse is over the `Select` or not.  If you're using a functional component, you can do that with the `useState` hook:

```
const [isOver, setIsOver] = useState(false);
```

Then, you need to modify the `Select` as follows:

```
<Select
    ...otherProps
    disabled={!isOver}
    onMouseEnter={onEnter}
    onMouseLeave={onLeave}
  >
```

And finally, you'd need to handle the entrance and exit of the mouse:

```
const onEnter = (e) => { setIsOver(true); }
const onLeave = (e) => { setIsOver(false); }
```

You may need to do some magic to deal with the the mouse being over the `MenuItems` rather than over the `Select`, but this will give you the framework for how to toggle it.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your complete explanation. It solved my problem.